# What is the name of the below method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

What is the name of the below method? :

```
100 = 10
10 = x

x = 10 * 10 / 100 = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Proportion Method (maybe). See, for example, http://amby.com/educate/math/4-2_prop.html .

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome.

Comment: For that first equality, do you mean $$\frac{100}{10}=\frac{10}{x}?$$ In that case, I've also heard the term [cross-multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication) used to describe the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the "[rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28mathematics%29#Rule_of_Three)".

${}{}$